# C#: How to use a derived class's const variable in base's constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, virtual, instantiation, derived-class

Thanks in advance,

My situation is that I have an abstract class called **Vehicle** that holds:

```
private List<Tire> m_Tires;
```

The thing is that the number of tires in the list is determined in the derived classes and varies between one and another, but the code needed for the instantiation is the same and therefore I would highly prefer to avoid code duplication and place that code (that instantiates **m_Tires**) in the abstract **Vehicle** class's constructor.

I first thought of using `protected abstract void initializeTires();` to be implemented in the derived classes and be called from Vehicle's constructor. I saw here it's bad programming and error prone.

So to make a long story short: **Is it possible to avoid the code duplication here or I'll just have to make peace with it?**

Comment: You could pass the tire count as a parameter to the base class.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `protected` constructor and chain it.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response. I don't know how it I missed it. You solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a:

```
initializeTires(int numberOfTyres);
```

in the base class and call this with the correct parameter in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

@Oded and a example of that is

```
public abstract class MyAbstract {
   private List<Tire> m_Tires;

   protected MyAbstract(int count) {
      m_Tires = new List<Tire>(count);
   }
}

public class MyClass : MyAbstract {
   public MyClass(int count) : base(count) { }   
}
```

Comment: Actually what will fit better in my case is:

public abstract class Vehicle {
   private List<Tire> m_Tires;

   protected Vehicle(int i_NumOfTires) {
      m_Tires = new List<Tire>(i_NumOfTires);
   }
}

public class Car : Vehicle {   
   private const int k_NumOfTires = 4
   
   public Car() : base(k_NumOfTires) { }   
}

Comment: yeah, i got a bit confused with conflicting information... you mentioned you needed to initialize based on a number, but your example init-method didn't take any arguments :)

Comment: I see where you got confused, my intention was that initializeTires would refer directly to the const variable.
It seemed clear to me when I wrote it, but I see it can be a bit confusing.

Comment: May i ask though what the purpose of initializing the list with a certain length? if its because it should be a fixed size, then use an array instead, since you can still keep adding to your list even if the number of tires exceeds the initial length.